# Strip HTML tags, but keep content within ( javascript / jquery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

Before you mark this as a duplicate, I searched SO and used many regexps not getting the results I was looking for.

I'm parsing the content of html emails and the styling and html of the emails is altering the styling of my page.

How can I remove all CSS and HTML from these string. I've tried regexps, but I always end up losing some content within the HTML.

I think PHP has a strip_tags function? That works perfectly. Is there something like that in javascript / jquery?

Or what is the algo for that function and how can I port it to js / jquery? Or something better that works well.

Here is an example of the string I am paring: http://pastebin.com/bw8zMNs9

Comment: Why don't you load emails into an iframe?

Comment: @Dmitry because the area I'm loading them in is small in width ( about 0.25vw ). I don't want to load the images as they look distorted. The text can wrap. All I need is the text.

Answer (score 1):

Regexp's aren't good to parse HTML. [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) seems to do what you want.
Try this:

```
$htmlString = $("<div>" + YOUR_HTML_STRING + "</div>");

$htmlString.find("style").remove();
$htmlString.find("script").remove();

var rawText = $htmlString.text();
```

Try it here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veg0w5x1/)